# jQuery hijacks TypeScript's 'this' reference

Tags: jquery, typescript

I am using jQuery inside my TypeScript class.

```
export class RedTextBox {
 private element : HTMLInputElement;
 private changed : Boolean;

 Attach(textbox : HTMLInputElement) {
   this.element = textbox;
   ChangeColor();
 }

 ChangeColor() {
  $(this.element).css("background", "red");

  $(this.element).on("change", function() { 
       this.Changed = true;  // 'this' here is not the object of Typescript      
   });
 }
}
```

In the above code I am getting an error saying `this.Changed` is not defined. I checked in debugger to find out that inside the jQuery event, 'this' is actually the HTML Element instead of TypeScript object. Is there an alternate 'this' or can we force jQuery to leave 'this' alone (no pun intended)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `function` to define an anonymous function it's `this` is not bound to the instance you defined it in, and jQuery leverages `call`/`apply` to give a value to `this` inside of those callbacks.

The easiest solution is to swap to arrow functions:

```
$(this.element).on("change", () => {
  this.Changed = true;      
});
```

When you define an arrow function, the value of `this` inside of the arrow function is tied to the value of `this` in the scope the function is defined.

Another, less desirable alternative is the classic usage of `that` or `self`:

```
const self = this;
$(this.element).on("change", function() {
  self.Changed = true;      
});
```

**EDIT**

One final note, if you already have a function and can't use one of the above options for accessing the context of the outer scope, you can force `this` to be what you want inside of a function using `Function.prototype.bind`. This example is mostly relevant if your event handlers/callbacks are members of a class.

```
ChangeColor() {
  $(this.element).on("change", this.HandleChange.bind(this))
}

HandleChange() {
  this.Changed = true;
}
```

This only works with the call to `bind`, if you forgot to bind it then you would end up with the same issue you started with. Also, binding on the fly like this can get costly as a new function has to be created every time `bind` is called. So generally you pre-bind your functions you hand out in the constructor.

```
class RedTextBox {
  constructor() {
    this.HandleChange = this.HandleChange.bind(this);
  }

  ChangeColor() {
    $(this.element).on("change", this.HandleChange);
  }

  HandleChange() {
    this.Changed = true;
  }
}
```

Notice how I only bind once in the constructor and then I freely pass the reference to `this.HandleChange` as the callback.

Comment: Can we use the `arrow functions` while still transpiling to ES5? I have to support IE9+

Comment: Generally speaking, yes. The transpiler should have have target rules for translating arrow functions to ES5. The second option is ES5 compatible and probably close to what you might end up with.

Answer (score 2):

Well, It's not jquery that's hijacking. It's how javascript works. When you pass along a callback, the callback 'caller' "takes" the scope "this" to itself. 
When using ES6 or later (if I'm not wrong) you can use => functions and, by doing this, you KEEP the contex. Like this:

```
export class RedTextBox {
private element : HTMLInputElement;
 private changed : Boolean;

 Attach(textbox : HTMLInputElement) {
   this.element = textbox;
   ChangeColor();
 }

 ChangeColor() {
  $(this.element).css("background", "red");

  $(this.element).on("change", /* THIS PART */() => { 
       this.Changed = true;  // 'this' here is not the object of Typescript      
   });
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This behavior is the standard way Javascript functions work. If you pass a function to `jQuery`, `jQuery` will be the one deciding what `this` to pass to the function, even if the function was originally a method of a class.

`ES2015` add arrow functions (`=>`) which capture `this` from the declaration context and this is probably what you should use:

```
$(this.element).on("change", () => { 
   this.Changed = true;  // this is capture from the class 
});
```